# Why functionToCallOnOk I pass to my function does not get called when I attach it to callback via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function-pointers

So I try such code:

```
function showAlertWithCallback(w, h, name, body_text, functionToCallOnOk) {
    prepareWindow();
    var ran_alert_number=Math.random()*50000;
    $("#alert_content").html(body_text + '<br/>' + '<input type=\"button\" class=\"eButton\" value=\"Cancel\" onClick=$(\".alert\").hide() />' + '<input id=\"general-alert-'+ ran_alert_number +'\" type=\"button\" class=\"eButton\" value=\"OK\" onClick=\"$(\'.alert\').hide();\"/>');
$('#general-alert-' + ran_alert_number).click(functionToCallOnOk);  
 // also tried $('#general-alert-' + ran_alert_number).click(function(){functionToCallOnOk();});
    showAlertBase(w, h, name);
}
```

called via something like:

```
showAlertWithCallback(
       600, 
       100 , 
       ('New name for to ' + file_title + ' file.'),
       '<input type="text" style="width:590px" class="text" value=\"' + file_title + '\">', 
       function(){
         alert("hi!");
       }
    );
```

runs with no errors (chrome debugger) but function does not get called on OK click. Why and how to fix such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.random()*50000` will produce a number like 38518.060150090605, which when you concatenate with `'#general-alert-'` in the jQuery call will produce a selector like this:

```
#general-alert-38518.060150090605
```

That will be treated as a selector which finds an element with id `general-alert-38518` and class `060150090605`, since the class name comes after the dot.

To make the random number, use, say, `Math.floor(Math.random()*5000)` instead.

A better option would be to use an incrementing global variable (eg, `_global_counter++` each time you use it), then you would not have a chance of getting two elements with the same id.

An even better solution would be to create actual DOM elements in JavaScript, attach events to those elements, *then* insert those elements into the correct place in the document. That way they won't need to have ids at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `onClick` attribute of the OK button.